# Terraform: Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm traying to loops to dynamically add acl rules and get errors:

> Error: Error in function call
> │
> │   on ..\modules\acl\ressources.tf line 8, in resource "aws_network_acl" "pub-acl":
> │    8:       rule_no    = element(ingress.value, 0)
> │     ├────────────────
> │     │ ingress.value is "http"
> │
> │ Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string.

**error details** :

```
╷
│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on ..\modules\acl\ressources.tf line 8, in resource "aws_network_acl" "pub-acl":
│    8:       rule_no    = element(ingress.value, 0)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ ingress.value is "https"
│
│ Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string.
╵
╷
│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on ..\modules\acl\ressources.tf line 9, in resource "aws_network_acl" "pub-acl":
│    9:       protocol   = element(ingress.value, 1)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ ingress.value is "http"
│
│ Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string.
╵
╷
│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on ..\modules\acl\ressources.tf line 9, in resource "aws_network_acl" "pub-acl":
│    9:       protocol   = element(ingress.value, 1)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ ingress.value is "https"
│
│ Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string.
╵
╷
│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on ..\modules\acl\ressources.tf line 10, in resource "aws_network_acl" "pub-acl":
│   10:       action     = element(ingress.value, 2)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ ingress.value is "http"
│
│ Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string.
╵
╷
│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on ..\modules\acl\ressources.tf line 10, in resource "aws_network_acl" "pub-acl":
│   10:       action     = element(ingress.value, 2)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ ingress.value is "https"
│
│ Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string.
╵
╷
│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on ..\modules\acl\ressources.tf line 11, in resource "aws_network_acl" "pub-acl":
│   11:       cidr_block = element(ingress.value, 3)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ ingress.value is "http"
│
│ Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string.
╵
╷
│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on ..\modules\acl\ressources.tf line 11, in resource "aws_network_acl" "pub-acl":
│   11:       cidr_block = element(ingress.value, 3)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ ingress.value is "https"
│
│ Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string.
╵
╷
│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on ..\modules\acl\ressources.tf line 12, in resource "aws_network_acl" "pub-acl":
│   12:       from_port  = element(ingress.value, 4)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ ingress.value is "http"
│
│ Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string.
╵
╷
│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on ..\modules\acl\ressources.tf line 12, in resource "aws_network_acl" "pub-acl":
│   12:       from_port  = element(ingress.value, 4)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ ingress.value is "https"
│
│ Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string.
╵
╷
│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on ..\modules\acl\ressources.tf line 13, in resource "aws_network_acl" "pub-acl":
│   13:       to_port    = element(ingress.value, 5)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ ingress.value is "http"
│
│ Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string.
╵
╷
│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on ..\modules\acl\ressources.tf line 13, in resource "aws_network_acl" "pub-acl":
│   13:       to_port    = element(ingress.value, 5)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ ingress.value is "https"
│
│ Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string.
```

My code structure is :

```
-- Dev
  -- main.tf
  -- vars.tf
-- modules
  -- acl
    -- ressources.tf
```

This is my **vars.tf**

```
variable "acl_rules" {
  type              = map (any)
  # [rule_no, protocol, action, cidr, from_port, to_port]
  default = {
    http            = [100, "tcp", "allow",  "0.0.0.0/0", 80, 80]
    https           = [110, "tcp", "allow",  "0.0.0.0/0", 443, 443]
    ssh             = [120, "tcp", "allow",  "0.0.0.0/0", 22, 22]
  }
}
```

This is my **main.tf**

```
module "acl" {
  source            = "../modules/acl"
  vpc_id            = module.vpc.vpcId 
  acl_rules         = var.acl_rules
  rules             = ["http", "https"]
}
```

this is my **ressources.tf**

```
resource "aws_network_acl" "pub-acl" {
 
  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.rules
    content {
      rule_no       = element(ingress.value, 0)
      protocol      = element(ingress.value, 1)
      action        = element(ingress.value, 2)
      cidr_block    = element(ingress.value, 3)
      from_port     = element(ingress.value, 4)
      to_port       = element(ingress.value, 5)
    }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: what is `var.rules`? Its not shown in your question.

Comment: Hello Marcin, it's in main.tf :       `rules = ["http", "https"]`. I noticed not using the variable acl_rules, could you please help to say how combine `var.rules` and `var.acl_rules`?

Comment: In input, client can give the rule to create ACL, eg:  `rules_for_webServ  = ["http", "https"]` , `rules_for_dbServ  = ["http", "https"]` ... then, it should create ACL rule for each every one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
resource "aws_network_acl" "pub-acl" {
 
  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.rules
    content {
      rule_no       = element(var.acl_rules[ingress.value], 0)
      protocol      = element(var.acl_rules[ingress.value], 1)
      action        = element(var.acl_rules[ingress.value], 2)
      cidr_block    = element(var.acl_rules[ingress.value], 3)
      from_port     = element(var.acl_rules[ingress.value], 4)
      to_port       = element(var.acl_rules[ingress.value], 5)
    }
  }
  
}
```